# mocking multiple response with mock in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I am trying to write unit test for the Rest client I wrote using mock

Lets say this class is `Foo` and has two methods.. `get_foo()` and `get_bar()`

Here is my Test class

```
fake_foo_response= 'foo'
class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.patcher = patch('foo', fake_foo_response)
    self.patcher.start()
    self.foo = Foo()

  def tearDown(self):
    self.patcher.stop()

  def test_get_foo(self):
    response = self.foo.get_foo()
    self.assertEqual(response,'foo')
```

I basically used this tutorial to get here: http://seminar.io/2013/09/27/testing-your-rest-client-in-python/

But now, i want to test bar as well.. how do i test bar with this approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may find this easier to do using MagicMocks instead of patches, something along these lines should help:

```
from mock import MagicMock

fake_foo_response = 'foo'
fake_bar_response = 'bar'

class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
        self.foo.get_foo = MagicMock(return_value=fake_foo_response)
        self.foo.get_bar = MagicMock(return_value=fake_bar_response)

    def test_get_foo(self):
        response = self.foo.get_foo()
        self.assertEqual(fake_foo_response, response)

    def test_get_bar(self):
        response = self.foo.get_bar()
        self.assertEqual(fake_bar_response, response)
```

However, I think you need to take a look at what you are actually testing in your example. All that you are really doing here is:

- Creating an instance of the `Foo` object.
- Patching a function to return a specific value.
- Calling the patched function (i.e. not the real function) and asserting the return value.

You are not actually testing the `get_foo` function at all, and therefore there is no real value to this test in the state you show above. However, the technique you are showing here can be very useful for testing something like a REST client (which has to call an external service outside of the unit under test). Let's assume that your real `get_foo` implementation does something like this:

1. Does some work with input parameters
2. Makes a call to an external URL, and gets a response (which is the part you want to mock)
3. Does some work with the response and possibly return something to the caller

If unit testing this function, you would want to write a test that tests `get_foo` and tests the behavior in points 1 and 3 above, but patches point 2. This is where patching in this style becomes highly valuable, as you can use this to test `get_foo` yet mocks out the call outside of the unit, for example:

```
class Foo:

    def get_foo(self, input):
        url_param = <do something with input>
        response = self._call_url(url_param)
        output = <do something with response>
        return output


class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
        self.foo._call_url = MagicMock(return_value='some response')

    def test_get_foo(self):
        output = self.foo.get_foo('bar')
        self.assertEqual('ni', output)
```

Now, you are able to use patching (via the `MagicMock` to test the code in your `get_foo` method) without having to rely on calling something outside of the unit.

Hope this helps.